# File object does not update parent property

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following simple code:

```
accessFile=accessFiles.next();
//accessFileId=accessFile.getId();
testRoot.removeFile(accessFile);
//accessFile=DriveApp.getFileById(accessFileId);
```

Later I test the

`accessFile.getParent().hasNext();`

and checking

`accessFile.getParent().next().getName();`

and see that the `accessFile` is still in `testRoot` folder.
When I load the `accessFile` again after `removeFile` (commented rows),
then it reflects the `removeFile()` action. In other words, it works fine.

I didn't find any explanation.Could you please advise?

Comment: Apps Script performs internal optimizations that can alter the execute order of statements you make, in order to improve performance. If you iterate the files in `testRoot` after calling `removeFile`, you will likely not find `accessFile` as it is clear to Apps Script that one action must occur first.

Comment: Also removeFile doesn't delete the file.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removeFile(File) so I believe the links are still there just the attributes have changed so you don't see it.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answers. I'm using removeFile to move it later into other folder.
The google script optimization is unexpected at least by me and I've lost a lot of time by searching for the problem. Perhaps it is matter of experience and I'm not so far from the beginning. :) Thank you!